# Sort article based on weighted tags in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am using following structure:

```
Table Article:
id
title

Table ArticleTags:
id
articleid
tagid

Table Tags:
id
tagname
preferenece [0-5]
```

Now I need to sort article based on multiple tags. Is it possible using mysql single query

Example:

```
article A is tagged by following tags and preference
pc 2
mobile 3
tech 1

article B is tagged by following tags and preference
tech 3
php 2
grails 4
mobile 2
```

Now if I want to sort by tags - mobile and tech, article B will rank first. If I sort only by mobile Article A will rank first.

Comment: What is preference ID?

Comment: And what do you mean by `tags`??

Comment: Sorry about preference id, it will be tag id. I've corrected that. Regarding tags, every article have multiple weighted tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tags have different weight for different articles IMHO it's only natural to have a preference (weight) column in `articletags` table instead of `tags` table. Otherwise you'll and up with multiple entries in tags with the same name but different weights.

Therefore I'd suggest you change your schema

```
CREATE TABLE articletags
  (`id` int, `articleid` int, `tagid` int, `preference` int);
CREATE TABLE tags
  (`id` int, `tagname` varchar(32));
```

Now all other rules to get the sum of weights per article and applying the order are the same

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM article a JOIN
(
  SELECT articleid, SUM(at.preference) total_preference
    FROM articletags at JOIN tags t
      ON at.tagid = t.id
   WHERE t.tagname IN ('mobile', 'tech')
   GROUP BY articleid
) q ON a.id = q.articleid
 ORDER BY q.total_preference DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/540a4/5)** demo

Answer (score 1):

The relationship of tables are not quite clear, I am thinking of the relationship like this:

`Article Table (id) <= (articleid) ArticleTags Table (tagid) => (id) Tags Table`

And by your given criteria, looks like the `SUM` of `preference` is used to sort the output.

So I ended up with this query:

```
SELECT A.title
    , SUM(T.preference) AS preferenceSum
    FROM Tags T
    INNER JOIN ArticleTags AT ON T.tagid = T.id
    INNER JOIN Article A ON A.id = AT.articleid
    WHERE T.tagname IN ('mobile', 'tech')
    GROUP BY A.id
    ORDER BY preferenceSum DESC;
```

And it is also unclear how there are `tags` with different `preference`. From your question, `mobile` and `tech` exists with different `preference`. Or are we missing some tables here.

Comment: I am checking the query. Sorry about preference id, it should be tag id and I've corrected that. You're correct, I need to sort by sum of preference of given tags. In tags table same tag can reside with multiple preferences.

Comment: No problem @biztiger, my query should work with your criteria then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them ordered by the highest tag preference then something like this:-

```
SELECT Article.id, Article.title, Sub1.MaxPreference
FROM Article
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Article.id, MAX(Tags.preference) AS MaxPreference
    FROM Article
    INNER JOIN ArticleTags ON Article.id = ArticleTags.articleid
    INNER JOIN Tags ON ArticleTags.tagid = Tags.id
    GROUP BY Article.id
) Sub1
ON Article.id = Sub1.id
ORDER BY Sub1.MaxPreference DESC
```

To limit it to only taking account of a couple of tags:-

```
SELECT Article.id, Article.title, Sub1.MaxPreference
FROM Article
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Article.id, MAX(Tags.preference) AS MaxPreference
    FROM Article
    INNER JOIN ArticleTags ON Article.id = ArticleTags.articleid
    INNER JOIN Tags ON ArticleTags.tagid = Tags.id
    WHERE Tags.tagname IN ('mobile','tech')
    GROUP BY Article.id
) Sub1
ON Article.id = Sub1.id
ORDER BY Sub1.MaxPreference DESC
```

If you want them ordered by the sum of the preferences then something like this:-

```
SELECT Article.id, Article.title, Sub1.SumPreference
FROM Article
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Article.id, SUM(Tags.preference) AS SumPreference
    FROM Article
    INNER JOIN ArticleTags ON Article.id = ArticleTags.articleid
    INNER JOIN Tags ON ArticleTags.tagid = Tags.id
    GROUP BY Article.id
) Sub1
ON Article.id = Sub1.id
ORDER BY Sub1.SumPreference DESC
```